# Reference a native dll so it appears in a subfolder of the UWP project

Tags: c++, uwp

I'm on a C# UWP gui app, which references a C++ UWP project, which itself uses native dlls (opengl and some others) without referencing them explicitly.
All is working correctly.

But it works only when i add the native dlls to the C# UWP project, and only at the root of the project. Which makes it very messy as there are about 40 dlls.

If i move these dlls in a subfolder of the project, as soon as a C# calls C++, it crashes with a message 'dll or one of its ref ... not found'.
I've already tried that https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/26013e5e-3ff1-44a0-8797-0474dabd12d0/uwpincluding-dlls-in-a-uwp-application-in-visual-studio?forum=wpdevelop

Any solution other than creating a post build event or custom msbuild code that copies dlls from the subfolder into the output root folder ?

The reference in the csproj file looks like this:

```
    <Content Include="..\..\..\..\..\..\..\opencv\bin\opencv_features2d411d.pdb" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Link>opencv_features2d411d.pdb</Link>
    </Content>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell me if you are referencing a C++ UWP project in C# UWP, and the C++ UWP project uses native dlls? If so, could you please tell me if your C++ UWP project is a Windows Runtime Component(C++/WinRT)?

Comment: I don''t know more than what i already wrote.

Comment: Maybe you could try to wrap you DLL into a [C++/WinRT Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/create-a-windows-runtime-component-in-cppwinrt), then reference the component in a C# UWP application.

Comment: There is already a C++ UWP library using these DLLs. But it references only the .h files. Is this component more than a UWP lib ?

Comment: C++/WinRT component can expose Win32 functionality to a UWP app written in C#, you can easily add the DLL header to the component by this [way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-160#to-add-the-dll-header-to-your-include-path) without adding the DLL files into the root of your project.

Comment: And you can easily use that component in your C# UWP app by adding a reference to the component referring to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/create-a-windows-runtime-component-in-cppwinrt#create-a-core-app-thermometercoreapp-to-test-the-windows-runtime-component).

Comment: The DLL is required to run the project. How do you run the project if you don''t add the DLL ? It's not Win32 built in functionality btw.